# Is it okay to use the exception as a condition in code?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm using Sqlalchemy and Fastapi and in one of the DB models I have unique constraint set to slug column. So every time someone tries to set the slug that already exists the code will throw an IntegrityError. I am using that except block to create a random slug and call that function recursively. Below are part of my code.

```
    def create(self,
           member_in: MemberCreateRequest, ) -> Member:
    print("[+] CREATE Member")
    try:
        member_item = Member(
            name=member_in.name,
            email=member_in.email,
            username=member_in.username,
            slug=member_in.slug,
        )
        self.session.add(member_item)
        self.session.commit()
        self.session.refresh(member_item)
        return member_item
    except IntegrityError as e:
        self.session.rollback()

        # add some random number to slug and try adding it again
        if "UNIQUE constraint failed: member.slug" in e.args[0]:
            member_in.slug = "{slug}-{random_number}".format(
                slug=member_in.slug, random_number=randint(100, 999)
            )
            return self.create(workspace_id, member_in)
        else:
            raise e
```

I want to know if it is okay to use the except block this way. If not could you point out what is wrong with the current approach and what I can do to make it better?

Thank You.

Comment: All you need to ask is are you handling the error in a way that is suitable to your needs?

Comment: I mean the code is working fine, but in case there are any changes to the error message this will not work as expected, which can be an issue since I might be using this approach at multiple places.

Comment: That is a different question to what you're asking here though. Whether you need a helper function i.e `validate_slug_exception` or similar is hard to answer

Comment: yes, I did think of that, have a variable that will contain the error message with the positional argument that can be changed using the string format function. but someone told me this is the wrong approach alltogether.

Comment: He said that I shouldn't be using exception as a condition and should never use a recursive function inside it because it can cause an infinite loop.

Comment: It's totally fine to do whatever you want as part of handling exceptions. Google `EAFP` and `LBYL` approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it okay to use the exception as a condition in code?

You are asking if you can use the `except` block similar to the `else` block.

Basically, you are handling the code. There are two approaches to Software Engineering in general.

1. `LBYL`: Look Before You Lead - This means to avoid exceptions by adding an `if`-`else` check.
2. `EAFP`: Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission - `try` something and then `except` the exception and handle it.

What you are doing is EAFP. And it's totally fine to consider an `except` block equivalent to `if` or `else` block.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out. This makes a lot of sense. I'm accepting this answer.